# Memset overwrites another array

Tags: c

I encountered a problem using the memset function (both the pre-implemented one and the one I made myself).

Here's the code where I get issues:

```
static char *ft_trim(char *input)
{
    char    *res;

    ft_putendl(input);   // Here I check my input string.
    res = ft_strnew(5);
    ft_memset(res, '0', 5); // I tried using memset(res, '0', 5);   same result
    res[5] = '\0';
    ft_putendl(input);   // Second check
```

What I want is having **res** be something like "00000". These lines do this just fine, but in the same time memset seems to be writing in my input chain. My output is the following :

```
lllllaarararttttRRR
lllllaararartttt00000
```

The first **input** prompt is okay, but them in the second one I lost some data.

In case it's needed for the answer, here's my **ft_memset**'s code:

```
void    *ft_memset(void *b, int c, size_t len)
{
    char                    *str;
    unsigned long int       i;

    str = (char*)b;
    i = 0;
    while (i < len)
    {
        str[i] = c;
        i++;
    }
    return (b);
}
```

Here's **ft_strnew** too :

```
char    *ft_strnew(size_t size)
{
    char    *str;

    if (!(str = (char*)(malloc(sizeof(char) * (size + 1)))))
        return (0);
    ft_strclr(str);
    return (str);
}
```

And there goes **ft_strclr**, just in case.

```
void    ft_strclr(char *s)
{
    int i;

    i = 0;
    while (s[i] != '\0')
    {
        s[i] = '\0';
        i++;
    }
}
```

**ft_putendl**

```
void    ft_putendl(char const *s)
{
    ft_putstr(s);
    write(1, "\n", 1);
}
```

**ft_putstr**

```
void    ft_putstr(char const *s)
{
    int i;

    i = 0;
    while (s[i] != '\0')
    {
        ft_putchar((char)s[i]);
        i++;
    }
}
```

**ft_putchar**

```
void    ft_putchar(char c)
{
   write(1, &c, 1);
}
```

As for the main, my code is placed in a function which is something like in 3 layers of function calls (main calls something which calls something which calls this portion). *input is the result of `ft_strnew(int)`, and is gradually filled by copying char by char.

As for the context, the only parts concerning said char * are here:

```
*origin being a string from **argv

tmp = ft_strnew(/*an int I get*/);
i = 0;
while (*origin)
{
    if (ft_isalpha(*origin) != 0)
    {
        tmp[i] = *origin;
        i++;
    }
    origin++;
}
```

And from there I send *tmp, which is the *input seen higher in the post

Comment: It looks like `ft_strnew` is returning a bad address.  What happens if you `printf("%p - %p", input, res);`?

Comment: @András Cottier  If you allocated an array of 5 characters then this statement writes outside the array  res[5] = '\0';

Comment: My guess is that the function call `ft_strnew(5);` allocates 5 bytes of memory, and you are writing over unauthorized memory by using `res[5] = '\0';`.

Comment: @András Cottier  Show function ft_strnew

Comment: @QuestionC `0x7f9bb8403290 - 0x7f9bb84032a0` is the prompt.
@VladfromMoscow My ft_strnew allocates one additional case for the ending '\0'.

Comment: Minor: `unsigned long int       i;` should be `size_t i;`

Comment: `while (s[i] != '\0')` does nort make sense as used in `ft_strnew()`.  `s[i]` is uninitialized and there is no control on how many times the loop will iterate..

Comment: @chux Corrected both changes, thanks. No change for the prompt, though.

Comment: Change `ft_strclr(str);` --> `memset(str, 0, size + 1);`  Drop `ft_strclr()`.

Comment: `(char*)(malloc(sizeof(char) * (size + 1)))` is so much harder to read than `malloc(size+1)`

Comment: Coding our own lib was the first project in my school, and implicite casts were more or less forbidden.

Comment: well, `(size+1)` has an implicit conversion because `1` is an `int`. If you follow your own rule you should write `(char*)(malloc(sizeof(char) * (size + (size_t)1)))`. Also `return(0)` should be `return((char *)0)`, `s[i] != '\0'` should be `s[i] != (char)'\0'`, and `str[i] = c;` should be `str[i] = (char)c;`, and `ft_memset(res, '0', 5);`  should be `ft_memset((void *)res, '0', (size_t)5);`

Answer (score 3):

OP `ft_strnew()` calls `ft_strclr()` which is broken beyond repair as it does not limit its iteration count (both in a maximum and minimum sense) and when used with ft_strnew()`,`ft_strclr()` it reads uninitialized memory.

Suggest:

```
char *ft_strnew(size_t length) {
  return calloc(length + 1, 1);  // calloc zero fills the allocated memory
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I made the changes. The main program still doesn't changes, though.

Comment: @OP `ft_putendl()` and `main()` are not posted, so I cannot help.

Comment: I'm not authorized to use most of libc functions if I didn't code them again myself.

Comment: @András Cottier As I lack clairvoyance, I do not know which functions are authorized or not.  Without a list, it is difficult to divine what is allowed.

Comment: For this project (recode shell command `ls` ), I may use write, opendir, readdir, closedir, stat, lstat, getpwuid, getgrgid, listxattr, getxattr, time, ctime, readlink, malloc, free, perror, strerror, exit. Although I don't think the problem is in my lib rather than in my code here. But if you really want the full code leading here, I can post it - but I'm sure there's gonna be plenty of new errors or optimization possibilities in it, and I don't want to get carried away.

Comment: This important info should be appended to your post.  BTW I am sure you can easily code a suitable `ft_calloc()` from `malloc()`.

Comment: Edited the main post.